# iOS 9.1 - iTunnes adding new version of app - Your changes couldn't be saved

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode7, itunes, itunes-store, ios9.1

[image]

I wan't to add a new version of my app. Somehow itunes doesn't allow it. Two days ago I added a new version of some other app and it worked perfectly.

I tried:

- Different version numbers (1.2, 2.0, etc.)
- Checking the version number against the Xcode version number in my app project
- Uploading my app from Xcode to itunes and than trying to add a new version

Has anyone solved this?

Is there a new way to adding the version number? Maybe somewhere in Xcode/Organizer?

Comment: It seems it's a new issue : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27283

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sent them contacted apple via the link in the error log box.

The error disappeared, and a new version has been created. I have recieved a e-mail considering the error report but no explanation or whatsoever.

It seems that apple has created and fixed the bug. Took them 4 hours ;).